# Figure Out Which OrderIDs are 0$ Payment Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am in need to some help writing a SQL 2012 query that will help me find and `mark` orderID's that are a $0.00 payments due to reversal(s)

So far I have:

```
Select Distinct a.orderID, a.orderPaid,
    (Select SUM((c1.linePrice + c1.lineShippingCost + c1.lineTaxCost + c1.lineOptionCost) * c1.lineQuantity) 
            From vwSelectOrderLineItems c1 Where c1.orderID = a.orderID) As OrderAmount,
    (Select SUM(b1.payAmount) FROM vwSelectOrderPayments b1 Where b1.orderID = a.orderID) as Payment,
    1 As IsReversal
From vwSelectOrders a
Left Outer Join vwSelectOrderPayments b On b.orderID = a.orderID
Where b.payValid = 1 AND a.orderPaid = 0
```

Which is returning me some $0 payments on some orders.  When I query that payment table with the orderID of these records, I can see that 2 payments were posted... 1 the original payment, 2 the reversal.

How Can I `flag` the `Orders` that are $0 payments?

## Oders

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblOrders](
    [orderID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [orderPaid] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [orderPaidOn] [datetime] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TblOrders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [orderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 50) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblOrders] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__TblOrders__order__1975C517]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [orderPaid]
```

## Order Line Items

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblOrderLineItems](
    [lineID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [orderID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [lineQuantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [linePrice] [money] NOT NULL,
    [lineShippingCost] [money] NOT NULL,
    [lineTaxCost] [money] NOT NULL,
    [lineOptionCost] [money] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TblOrderLineItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [lineID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 50) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblOrderLineItems] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TblOrderLineItems_lineShippingCost]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [lineShippingCost]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblOrderLineItems] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TblOrderLineItems_lineTaxCost]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [lineTaxCost]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblOrderLineItems] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TblOrderLineItems_lineOptionCost]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [lineOptionCost]
GO
```

## Order Payments

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblOrderPayments](
    [paymentID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [orderID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [payAmount] [money] NOT NULL,
    [payPosted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [payValid] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TblOrderPayments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [paymentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 50) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblOrderPayments] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TblOrderPayments_payValid]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [payValid]
GO
```

## Views

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSelectOrderLineItems] AS 
SELECT linePrice, lineShippingCost, lineTaxCost, lineOptionCost, lineQuantity 
FROM [dbo].[TblOrderLineItems]

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSelectOrderPayments] AS
SELECT paymentID, orderID, payAmount, payValid
FROM dbo.TblOrderPayments

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSelectOrders] AS
SELECT orderID , orderPaid
FROM dbo.TblOrders
```

## Note

I cannot change the table structure

Comment: Can you give us the table definitions please

Comment: You are doing RBAR queries, this will preform terrible. Once we get the table definitions we can help you with that too.

Comment: what is the definition of the view?

Comment: question editted with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct a.orderid,
                a.orderPaid,
                c.OrderAmount
                d.Payment
From vwSelectOrders AS a
INNER JOIN ( Select SUM((linePrice + lineShippingCost + lineTaxCost + lineOptionCost) * lineQuantity) As orderAmount,OrderID
             From vwSelectOrderLineItems group by orderid) AS C on c.orderID = a.orderID
INNER JOIN (Select SUM(payAmount) as Payment,orderID FROM vwSelectOrderPayments WHERE isnull(SUM(PayAmount),0) > 0 GROUP BY OrderID) AS d ON d.orderID = a.orderID
Left Outer Join vwSelectOrderPayments b On b.orderID = a.orderID
Where b.payValid = 1 AND a.orderPaid = 0 AND
```

This is a better query as you do not have to us a correlated subquery. Correlated queries are when a subquery references an outerquery row. This isn't optimal because every row the outerquery runs the correlated subquery will execute.  Once you give us table definitions we can probably fix the overall data return of your query.

Comment: @07th Web Design, the compile time errors are fixed. Just a word of caution, you should look over all the code you cut and paste and run directly in your IDE.

Comment: @o7thWebDesign, correct it doesnt fix your problem. I am working on that now

Comment: sry... meant no offense :)

Comment: @o7thWebDesign no problem. When you get a minute will you put the definition of the view in

Comment: @o7thWebDesign try that, that should remove all items that have 0 payment or null in the payment field.

Comment: `Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.`

Comment: on top of that, still doesn't answer the question.  I'm not looking to get rid of anything.  I want to mark the records which are marked as `orderPaid = 0`, and have a payment reversed...

Comment: If we can add something in like: `(IIF(@b > 1 AND @a = 0, 'True', 'False')) As HasReversal` as a column in the select list, where `@b` is the count of payments per order, and `@a` is the $0.00 dollar amount of the sum of the per order payment, it would be golden...

Comment: you helped me figure it out, so you get the answer: I needed to add in: `INNER JOIN (Select COUNT(paymentID) as PaymentCount, orderID 
    FROM vwSelectOrderPayments GROUP BY orderID) AS e ON e.orderID = a.orderID` and a new couple columns to the select list: `e.PaymentCount,
    (IIF(e.PaymentCount > 1 AND d.Payment = 0, 
      'True', 
      'False')) As HasReversal`